# All matrix row combination

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

Using the matrix created below:

```
matrix = []
for i in range(0, N):
    row = []
    for j in range(0, M):
        row.append(i *j)
    matrix.append(row)
```

I need get all row combinations from this matrix. For example:

```
[matrix[1][1], matrix[2][1], ... , matrix[m][1]]
[matrix[1][1], matrix[2][1], ... , matrix[m][2]]
[...]
[matrix[1][1], matrix[2][n], ... , matrix[m][n]]
[...]
[matrix[1][n], matrix[2][n], ... , matrix[m][n]]
```

Any ideas on how to do this using Python?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more which combinations you want?

Comment: For example, how are the first two rows different. They both start at [1][1], but one ends at [m][1], and the other ends at [m][2]. It isn't clear to me how one gets from one to the other.

Comment: I think the OP wants all possible combinations if you choose one object from each column. So for a 3 x 3 matrix, there should be 27 combinations.

Comment: @EliRose: I assumed it was one object from each row, since `matrix[x]` is row x.

Comment: On a related note, indices are zero-based - these should start with `matrix[0]`

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting off with a simpler way to define your matrix:

```
>>> M, N = 3, 4
>>> matrix = [
    [i * j for j in range(M)]
    for i in range(N)
]
>>> matrix
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 6]]
```

Then with `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

for row_combination in itertools.product(*matrix):
    print row_combination
```

```
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 6)
...
(0, 2, 4, 3)
(0, 2, 4, 6)
```